# Add Event Listener for <td> tag problem - JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it whenever the user clicks the td tag, it will execute this function, But whenever i reload the page the function is executed automatically without the need of clicking the  tag, how can I fix this?

```
document.querySelector('td').addEventListener('click', viewUserComplaints())

function viewUserComplaints() {
    console.log('test')
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event handler.

Comment: The linked article and "duplicate" is not the reason for OP's problem.  Here you go op.  `document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(ele => ele.addEventListener("click", viewUserComplaints));`  https://jsfiddle.net/nupg89t2/1/